# Java SWT ProgressMonitorDialog with UI Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swt, progressdialog

I want to display a simple progress monitor dialog to the user while some data is searched in the local database of the application and the displayed in the UI.

I currently use a ProgressMonitorDialog in which I perform the search in the UI thread with `Display.getDefault().asyncExec`. Now the search is realy slow. What would be the correct thread usage to display the progress dialog, perform searches in the database and display the result to the User without the performance loss.

```
 private void doSearchWithProgressDialog() {
        ProgressMonitorDialog progressDialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(null);

        try {
            progressDialog.run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {

                @Override
                public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
                    // display progress monitor dialog while searching
                    monitor.beginTask("Waiting..."), IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);

                    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // perform database query
                            doSearchAndDisplayResult();
                        }
                    });

                    monitor.done();

                }
            });
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this part of an Eclipse plugin? A `Job` would be appropriate if it is.

Comment: It is part of an Eclipse RCP application.

Answer (score 0):

For long running code in an Eclipse plugin or RCP use a `Job`:

```
class MyJob extends Job
{
  public MyJob()
  {
    super("title");

    setUser(true);
  }

  @Override
  protected IStatus run(final IProgressMonitor monitor)
  {
    ... your code

    return Status.OK_STATUS;
  }
}
```

Use with:

```
Job myJob = new MyJob();
myJob.schedule();
```

The call to `setUser(true)` means the job will display a progress dialog if it does not finish within a few seconds.